# Resources to learn about Bose-Einstein condensation as an undergraduate

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, bose-einstein-condensate

For context, I am an undergraduate student who has background in undergrad QM and Electrodynamics (I've covered everything in both Griffiths textbooks). I do not know much, however, about statistical physics or thermodynamics.

I need to learn the theory behind Bose-Einstein condensation for an upcoming research project. Are there any good books or resources that discuss the topic at an undergraduate level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **Don Koks ["Microstates, Entropy and Quanta: An Introduction to Statistical Mechanics"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3030024288)**.

I like its mathematically rigorous approach. The author actually covers the Mathematics needed in the beginning of the book and then proceeds to build the physics on it. This is important because it helps the reader understand what these spooky differentials that appear everywhere in Physics actually are and why the manipulations with them are legit.

However, besides rigor and derivation, a significant emphasis is also placed on the intuition behind every concept, which is crucial in statistical mechanics, since many seemingly unreasonable assumptions have to be made all the time.

Thus, this book is basically a **self-contained** resource for what you need.
$\rule[0.5cm]{17.5cm}{0.6pt}$
If you want something **shorter**, more concise, I found **[these lectures](https://people.bath.ac.uk/pystab/PH20029_notes.pdf)** to be a decent material. They are **only $70$ pages long** but cover all the basics you need. However, they don't go nearly as deep into the intuition, don't cover nearly as many topics (however, the basics for Bose-Einstein statistics are there) and don't explain the math used.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this one:
https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9904034v2
It covers more the experimental details, but this makes the topic easier to grasp